# Bootstrap dropdown menu: not close when click outside the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this script to control open/collapse menu items:

```
$('.dropdown').on({
    "click": function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.dropdown-toggle').length && $(this).parents('.dropdown').length === ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown').length - 1)) {
            $(this).data('closable', true);
        } else {
            $(this).data('closable', false);
        }
    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown": function(event) {
        hide = $(this).data('closable');
        $(this).data('closable', true);
        return hide;
    }
});
```

But I need to create a conditional that if user click outside the menu, the open item not close.

This question involves Bootstrap specificities. Just using:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event)
```

Not answer my question completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to detect if you are out of the menu.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.dropdown-toggle').length) {
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I add $('.dropdown').on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(event) {return false; }); inside the function, but the menu still close when click in other part of the page.

Comment: Sorry i missed that you didnt want to close if clicked outside. In this case you can try with event.stopPropagation(); but im not sure if other things arent touched

Comment: This script work in part. The problem it stop all other Bootstrap javascript module in page, lake panels and carousel. Any idea?

Comment: Nope. Now, the menu was close when click outside.